# Select Sort by Departure on Makemytrip using Vba Internet Explorer

Tags: html, vba, excel, internet-explorer

I am trying to select sort by Departure (early) on makemytrip (link given below) using Vba Internet explorer but not able to do it.

Link:- https://www.makemytrip.com/air/search?tripType=O&itinerary=DEL-DXB-D-30Nov2017&paxType=A-1&cabinClass=E

Please check the code given below and help the line to be get added for the same.

```
Sub mmtlink()

Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

IE.Visible = True

IE.navigate "https://www.makemytrip.com/air/search?tripType=O&itinerary=DEL-DXB-D-30Nov2017&paxType=A-1&cabinClass=E"

IE.document.getElementById("sorterText").Click

End sub
```

Comment: Please review [Ask] and [MCVE].  What have you tried? What were the result?  What exactly did you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the vague discription, I had a short look on the link you provided.

Try to fill a `iHTMLElementCollection` with `IE.document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown pull-right c-dropdown sortby-dropdown")`.
This will most likely you a collection of just one element - the div class containing a `<button>` and a `<ul>`. The `<ul>` contains some `<li>`, where the third one contains the Departure sorting option.

You can point to that option from your div element via the children - for example: `divelement.children(1).children(2).children(0).click`

Hope that helps you to get the answer somehow. Next time: @jwdonahue said it in the comments... you need to provide some more information on your problem, what you tried, what are the exact problems, what did you try already, what is your scope?

Comment: Thanks for your support sorry for less descriptive question. Finally able to do the needful full coding given below for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Buntes Lama for the great help. Please check below the answer of the question i asked.

```
Sub mmtlink()

Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim htmldoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim all As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim one As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

'Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

IE.Visible = True

IE.navigate "https://www.makemytrip.com/air/search?tripType=O&itinerary=DEL-DXB-D-30Nov2017&paxType=A-1&cabinClass=E"

 Do While IE.Busy = True Or IE.readyState <> 4
 Loop

    Set htmldoc = IE.document

    Set all = htmldoc.getElementsByClassName("sortbytype")
    For Each one In all
       If one.getAttribute("Innertext") = "from BOM (early)" Then
            one.Click
       End If
    Next one

Next i
End Sub
```